# Putting it in a method properly (TypeScript Newbie)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript1.8

Hello fellow programmers, i am new with programming and typescript. My question is how can i put this code seperatly in a method.

```
var item = new RoadMapExampleItem();
                                        item.calculatedCompleted = m.calculatedCompleted;
                                        item.estimatedCompleted = m.estimatedCompleted;
                                        item.epicId = e.id;
                                        item.epicText = e.name;
                                        item.initiativeId = i.id;
                                        item.initiativeText = i.name;
                                        item.mileStoneId = m.id;
                                        item.mileStoneText = m.name;
                                        item.epicProgress = e.progress;
                                        item.mileStoneProgress = m.progress;
                                        item.initiativeProgress = i.progress;
                                        item.versionId = v.id;
                                        item.versionText = v.versionText;
                                        result.push(item);
                                    });
```

this is the whole code

```
private buildRoadMapExampleItems(versions: Version[]): RoadMapExampleItem[] {
        var result = new Array<RoadMapExampleItem>();

        if (versions != null)
            versions.forEach(v => {
                if (v.mileStones != null)
                    v.mileStones.forEach(m => {
                        if (m.initiatives != null && m.initiatives.length > 0) {
                            m.initiatives.forEach(i => {
                                if (i.epics != null && i.epics.length > 0) {
                                    i.epics.forEach(e => {
                                        var item = new RoadMapExampleItem();
                                        item.calculatedCompleted = m.calculatedCompleted;
                                        item.estimatedCompleted = m.estimatedCompleted;
                                        item.epicId = e.id;
                                        item.epicText = e.name;
                                        item.initiativeId = i.id;
                                        item.initiativeText = i.name;
                                        item.mileStoneId = m.id;
                                        item.mileStoneText = m.name;
                                        item.epicProgress = e.progress;
                                        item.mileStoneProgress = m.progress;
                                        item.initiativeProgress = i.progress;
                                        item.versionId = v.id;
                                        item.versionText = v.versionText;
                                        result.push(item);
                                    });
                                }
                                else {
                                    var item = new RoadMapExampleItem();
                                    item.calculatedCompleted = m.calculatedCompleted;
                                    item.estimatedCompleted = m.estimatedCompleted;
                                    item.initiativeId = i.id;
                                    item.initiativeText = i.name;
                                    item.mileStoneId = m.id;
                                    item.mileStoneText = m.name;
                                    item.versionId = v.id;
                                    item.versionText = v.versionText;
                                    item.mileStoneProgress = m.progress;
                                    item.initiativeProgress = i.progress;
                                    result.push(item);
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method taking "e" as a parameter, and afterwards you push it in the result array. So inside the

```
 i.epics.forEach()
```

you could write something like

```
 i.epics.forEach(e => result.push(this.createItem(e)));
```

And create second method under that method block like

```
private createItem(e) : RoadMapExampleItem
{
             var item : RoadMapExampleItem = new RoadMapExampleItem();
                                    item.calculatedCompleted = m.calculatedCompleted;
                                    item.estimatedCompleted = m.estimatedCompleted;
                                    item.epicId = e.id;
                                    item.epicText = e.name;
                                    item.initiativeId = i.id;
                                    item.initiativeText = i.name;
                                    item.mileStoneId = m.id;
                                    item.mileStoneText = m.name;
                                    item.epicProgress = e.progress;
                                    item.mileStoneProgress = m.progress;
                                    item.initiativeProgress = i.progress;
                                    item.versionId = v.id;
                                    item.versionText = v.versionText;
 return item;
 }
```

This would be a way to split off the code.

But if I can give a bit more information rather than just say how to split off exactly what you asked. IT is probably a bit messy to have "item.epicId = e.id, item.epicText = e.name,..". 
This might be a good place to take a look at the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). (If you only just started out programming however, I wouldn't really worry about this yet, design patterns is something that you will learn later.

In addition, it may be wise to note that it is typescript, so you can use "types". When you create "item", you might want to use `item : RoadMapExampleIem`. And finally, instead of `var` you might want to use `let`in the future.

-- Also note that it might be wise to split it off in even more methods, you still have quite a few levels of indentation. in this part

```
    if (versions != null)
        versions.forEach(v => {
            if (v.mileStones != null)
                v.mileStones.forEach(m => {
                    if (m.initiatives != null && m.initiatives.length > 0) {
                        m.initiatives.forEach(i => {
                            if (i.epics != null && i.epics.length > 0) {
```

But it is good that you are thinking of methods already! ;-)

Comment: I graciously thank you. I am working on it right now.

Comment: @CecilBoye You are welcome. If this solved your problem you can let others know by accepting this answer as the solution ;-)

Comment: absolutly will do !

Comment: I am halfway there, my only problem now is it cant find e as aparameter. it says [ts] Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type. (parameter) e: any. Do i have to import something?

Comment: Is there a way you could share the current code you have somewhere? (Pastebin or something) so I could have a look. It wouldn't be an import for this.

Comment: Never mind, it worked. I only had to import a couple of things. But your code worked 95% for me so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

RoadMapExampleItem

```
class RoadMapExampleItem {
   constructor(public calculatedCompleted:number, public estimatedCompleted: number) //repeat all fields
}
```

Usage

```
 var item = new RoadMapExampleItem(m.calculatedCompleted, m.estimatedCompleted);
```